# tests not found in bamboo when changing user agent

Tags: python, selenium, user-agent, bamboo

I have a set of tests to be run in Bamboo with Selenium&Python.

I've added the following to my script (so that the tests are run with the iPhone user agent, and not the default one):

**

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override",
                           "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

**

When running locally, all tests are correctly run, but in Bamboo, I get the following error: "Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found."

I really need to use a mobile user agent, otherwise, the tests will be run on the desktop version of the app, which is not what I want at this point.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I use JUnit Parser for parsing the test results, so the problem might reside with this.

Comment: It seemed the problem got resolved. I think that what fixed it is modifying _Specify custom results directories_ to be ***.xml**